# Interpretation of 'ufactor' on a toy graph clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, metis

I am trying to do a imbalanced partition by METIS. I do not need equal number of vertices in each cluster(which is done by default in METIS). My graph has no constraints, it's a undirected unweighted graph. Here is a example toy graph clustered by METIS without no `ufactor` parameter.

[image]

Then, i tried with different `ufactor` and at value 143, `METIS` starts to 
do the expected cluster like the following-

[image]

Can anybody interpret this. Eventually, I want to find a way to guess an `ufactor` from any unbalanced and undirected graph that will minimize the normalized cut without doing any balance necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Imbalance=1+(ufactor/1000)`. By default `imbalance=1`. Number of vertex in largest cluster-

```
 imbalance*(number of vertex/number of cluster)
```

For first picture(default clustering)- number of vertex in larges cluster-
`1*(14/2)=7`, so the second cluster is also `14-7=7`
In the second picture(ufactor 143)-

```
imbalance=1+143/1000=1.143

so, 1.143*(14/2)=8.001
```

That allows the largest cluster to have 8 vertex.